# dplyr: Subtracting values group-wise by group that matches given condition

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

right now I'm refactoring an 'base'-based R script by using 'dplyr' instead.

Basically, I want to group_by Gene and subtract the values group-wise by a group that matches a given condition. In this case, I want values of Gene == 'C' and subtract them from all others.

Simplified data:

```
x <- data.frame('gene' = c('A','A','A','B','B','B','C','C','C'),
                'sample' = rep_len(c('wt','mut1','mut2'),3),
                'value' = c(32.3,31,30.5,25,25.3,22.1,20.5,21.2,19.8))

  gene sample value
1    A     wt  32.3
2    A   mut1  31.0
3    A   mut2  30.5
4    B     wt  25.0
5    B   mut1  25.3
6    B   mut2  22.1
7    C     wt  20.5
8    C   mut1  21.2
9    C   mut2  19.8
```

Desired output:

```
  gene sample value deltaC
1    A     wt  32.3   11.8
2    A   mut1  31.0    9.8
3    A   mut2  30.5   10.7
4    B     wt  25.0    4.5
5    B   mut1  25.3    4.1
6    B   mut2  22.1    2.3
7    C     wt  20.5    0.0
8    C   mut1  21.2    0.0
9    C   mut2  19.8    0.0
```

I base, it's not a big deal, but I'm wondering whether there is a simple solution using dplyr.

'Pseudo'code:

```
df %>%
    group_by(Gene) %>%
    mutate(deltaC = Value - Value(where Gene == 'C'))
```

Is there any kind of function that allows me to access only those values of Gene == 'C'? Of course I could also do a subset before, but I would like to do it in one step :)

Answer (score 8):

You basically had it! You can subset the data frame based on any condition within your mutate call:

```
df <- data.frame('gene' = c('A','A','A','B','B','B','C','C','C'),
                 'sample' = rep_len(c('wt','mut1','mut2'),3),
                 'value' = c(32.3,31,30.5,25,25.3,22.1,20.5,21.2,19.8))
```

Nicholas Hassan pointed out a problem with the original version of this answer. While you can group by "gene" and then mutate using a filtered version of the original data.frame, what you most likely want to do is to group by "sample" and then subset within the sample group on "gene":

```
df %>%
    group_by(sample) %>%
    mutate(deltaC = value - value[gene == 'C'])

# A tibble: 9 x 4
# Groups:   sample [3]
  gene  sample value deltaC
  <fct> <fct>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 A     wt      32.3   11.8
2 A     mut1    31      9.8
3 A     mut2    30.5   10.7
4 B     wt      25      4.5
5 B     mut1    25.3    4.1
6 B     mut2    22.1    2.3
7 C     wt      20.5    0  
8 C     mut1    21.2    0  
9 C     mut2    19.8    0
```

Within the grouped data.frame, mutate acts on each group as its own mini-data frame, so you can subset the `value` vector to just the row where `gene == 'C'` and subtract that from the entire `value` variable in that group to make `deltaC`.

Comment: But is there also a way NOT to use the 'base'-based bracket/dollar-notation? So for instance something specific for dply? :)

Comment: Sure, you can use `filter` to do basically the same thing

Comment: Great! Thank you very much!

Comment: @divibisan Thanks for this! Can you explain how the group_by works on gene? When I approached it, I thought you would have to group on sample. How does it know to subtract row 7 from rows 1 and 4 (and 7) based on them both being wt if it's grouped on gene?

Comment: @NicholasHassan You're absolutely right. The OP said they wanted to group on "gene", and the subtraction worked correctly because each group was ordered on "sample" in the same way, but if they weren't then you would have gotten incorrect results. Grouping on "sample" and then subsetting the variable within mutate is definitely the better way to do this. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 3):

If you wanted to avoid the `$` completely, you could use `dplyr::pull` like so:

```
df %>%
  group_by(gene) %>%
  mutate(deltaC = value - filter(., gene == 'C') %>% pull(value))
```

`dplyr::pull` is basically just the pipe friendly, dplyr equivalent to `df$value` or `df$[["value"]]`

Also, using the `.` inside of the filter statement represents the data that is being piped into the mutate statement.