# dplyr: Subtracting values group-wise by group that matches given condition - unequal group size

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a dataframe similar to this one:

```
UE1 <- c(rep("A", 6), rep("B", 4))
UE2 <- c(rep("T1", 3), rep("T2", 3), rep("T1", 4))
UE3 <- c(rep(c("ctrl", "X", "Y"), 2), "ctrl", "X", "Y", "Z")
value <- c(10, 20, 30, 20, 40, 60, 100, 200, 300, 400)

unequal_gp <- tibble(UE1, UE2, UE3, value)

> unequal_gp
# A tibble: 10 x 4
   UE1   UE2   UE3   value
   <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl>
 1 A     T1    ctrl     10
 2 A     T1    X        20
 3 A     T1    Y        30
 4 A     T2    ctrl     20
 5 A     T2    X        40
 6 A     T2    Y        60
 7 B     T1    ctrl    100
 8 B     T1    X       200
 9 B     T1    Y       300
10 B     T1    Z       400
```

I want to generate a new column, `delta_v`, which contains values of `value`, less the value of the control (`ctrl`) in UE3, with data grouped by UE1 and UE2 - giving this as my expected result:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 4
   UE1   UE2   UE3   value   delta_v
   <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 A     T1    ctrl     10   0
 2 A     T1    X        20   10
 3 A     T1    Y        30   20
 4 A     T2    ctrl     20   0
 5 A     T2    X        40   20
 6 A     T2    Y        60   40
 7 B     T1    ctrl    100   0
 8 B     T1    X       200   100
 9 B     T1    Y       300   200
10 B     T1    Z       400   300
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49536016/dplyr-subtracting-values-group-wise-by-group-that-matches-given-condition) answer is close to what i want, and works on a similar dataframe which has equal group sizes (but only when i group by E3, which i dont understand...?):

```
E1 <- c(rep("A", 6), rep("B", 6))
E2 <- c(rep("T1", 3), rep("T2", 3), rep("T1", 3), rep("T2", 3))
E3 <- c(rep(c("ctrl", "X", "Y"), 4))
value <- c(10, 20, 30, 20, 40, 60, 40, 70, 100, 100, 200, 300)

equal_gp <- tibble(E1, E2, E3, value)

equal_gp %>%
  group_by(E3) %>% #only works if i group by E3...?
  mutate(delta_v = value - filter(., E3 == "ctrl") %>% pull(value))
```

Giving:

```
   E1    E2    E3    value delta_v
   <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 A     T1    ctrl     10       0
 2 A     T1    X        20      10
 3 A     T1    Y        30      20
 4 A     T2    ctrl     20       0
 5 A     T2    X        40      20
 6 A     T2    Y        60      40
 7 B     T1    ctrl     40       0
 8 B     T1    X        70      30
 9 B     T1    Y       100      60
10 B     T2    ctrl    100       0
11 B     T2    X       200     100
12 B     T2    Y       300     200
```

but when i follow the same logic using the unequal group size

```
unequal_gp %>%
  group_by(UE3) %>% 
  mutate(delta_v = value - filter(., UE3 == "ctrl") %>% pull(value))
```

the `mutate()` fails and i get this error:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `delta_v`.
x Input `delta_v` can't be recycled to size 3.
i Input `delta_v` is `value - filter(., UE3 == "ctrl") %>% pull(value)`.
i Input `delta_v` must be size 3 or 1, not 3.
i The error occured in group 4: UE3 = "Z".
```

From the error it looks like the unequal group size is the problem, but i have no idea how to fix it.  Any suggestions most welcome - ideally sticking to the tidyverse.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use :

```
library(dplyr)

unequal_gp %>% 
   group_by(UE1, UE2) %>% 
   mutate(delta_v = value - value[UE3 == 'ctrl'])

#   UE1   UE2   UE3   value delta_v
#   <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 A     T1    ctrl     10       0
# 2 A     T1    X        20      10
# 3 A     T1    Y        30      20
# 4 A     T2    ctrl     20       0
# 5 A     T2    X        40      20
# 6 A     T2    Y        60      40
# 7 B     T1    ctrl    100       0
# 8 B     T1    X       200     100
# 9 B     T1    Y       300     200
#10 B     T1    Z       400     300
```

The above would work flawlessly if you have only one value of `'ctrl'` in `EU3` for each group, if you have multiple values you can use `match` to select the first value.

```
unequal_gp %>%
  group_by(UE1, UE2) %>%
  mutate(delta_v = value - value[match('ctrl', UE3)])
```

and same logic in `data.table` :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(unequal_gp)[, delta_v := value - value[match('ctrl', UE3)], .(UE1, UE2)]
```

Comment: I just wanted to post the *exact* same answer... :D

Comment: Well, we all have been there, haven't we? ;-)

Comment: Me too @MartinGal! No-one can beat Ronak to a `dplyr` answer though (except maybe akrun - sometimes!)

Comment: Is God omnipresent? Maybe, but Ronak surely is :D